# Constant Contact API - (403) Forbidden adding new contact

Tags: asp.net, api

I am trying to add a new contact to a mailing list using the Constant Contact API. I have a simple asp.net form and am executing the following function but I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." My function comes directly from Constant Contact but go figure!

[Constant Contact API](http://community.constantcontact.com/t5/Getting-Started-with-API-s/Last-name/td-p/44749)

```
Public Function AddContact(ByVal UserEmailAddress As String, ByVal ContactListNumber As Integer) As String
    Try
        Dim xml As String
        xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>" & _
        "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>" & _
            "<title type='text'></title>" & _
            "<updated>2008-07-23T14:21:06.407Z</updated>" & _
            "<author></author>" & _
            "<id>data:,none</id>" & _
            "<summary type='text'>Contact</summary>" & _
            "<content type='application/vnd.ctct+xml'>" & _
                "<Contact xmlns='http://ws.constantcontact.com/ns/1.0/'>" & _
                    "<EmailAddress>" & UserEmailAddress.ToString() & "</EmailAddress>" & _
                    "<OptInSource>ACTION_BY_CONTACT</OptInSource>" & _
                    "<ContactLists>" & _
                        "<ContactList id='http://api.constantcontact.com/ws/customers/[username]/lists/" & ContactListNumber.ToString() & "'/>" & _
                    "</ContactLists>" & _
                "</Contact>" & _
            "</content>" & _
        "</entry>"

        ' Set up the request
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.constantcontact.com/ws/customers/[username]/contacts/")
        Dim byteData As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.ToString())
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml"
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("[api key]%[username]", "[password]")

        ' Send the request
        Dim postStream As Stream
        postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        response = request.GetResponse()

    Catch ex As WebException
        Return ex.ToString
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

403 error for constant contact means the password is wrong, or that the string with the password is misconfigured. They specify `[your_api_key]%[your_constantcontact_username]:[password]` for their authentication. Though they are saying that this is deprecated, and everyone should move to oauth 2.0 now(or at least before 2013). Then you won't have to pass the password anymore.